# Indexing a multidimensional array from a list of indices in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot, indexing

Say I have an array of the form

```
array = np.random.rand(50, 50, 2)
```

and I have a list of tuples of indices, which will contain duplicates:

```
indices = [(0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 2), (1, 1), (0, 3), (0, 2)]
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a scatterplot of the array elements taken from the indices, with the 3rd dimension of the array giving the x and y coordinates of the point to be plotted. I have tried a few different things but realized that simple array indexing won't give me what I'm looking for because of the way that broadcasting works. I can implement this by iterating over the array and adding the points I want to a new array but that strikes me as unpythonic and I want to make sure I learn correct habits.

Comment: Does `array([[0,0,0,1,0,0], [2,3,2,1,3,2], :]` give the desired elements - a (6,2) array?

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, inspired by hpaulj above. I can convert the list of tuples of indices to an array, and use the long dimension of the resulting array to index my large array, like so:

```
index_array = np.array(indices)
reduced_array = array[index_array[:,0],index_array[:,1],:]
```

and then use reduced_array as an input to my scatter plot.